Compute $\int_{\phi_1}^{\phi_2} \left( \sum_{n=0}^N a_n \cos(n \phi) \right)^2 \,\text{d}\phi$ analytically?
For a computational model I need to evaluate the following integral many times:
$$
I(\phi_1, \phi_2) = \int_{\phi_1}^{\phi_2} \left( \sum_{n=0}^N a_n \cos(n \phi) \right)^2 \,\text{d}\phi,
$$
where I have an array of coefficients $\{a_n\}$.
I'm currently using numerical quadrature, but this has become a performance bottleneck. I have a feeling this integral has an analytical solution, but I've been unsuccessful researching one.
I've also been unsuccessful deriving one. Using the multinomial theorem, I think I can rewrite the series
$$
\left( \sum_{n=0}^N a_n \cos(n \phi) \right)^2 = \sum_{k_0+k_1+\ldots+k_N=2} \frac{2}{k_0! k_1! \ldots k_N!} \prod_{m=0}^N \left( a_m \cos(m\phi) \right)^{k_m}
$$
$$
\Rightarrow \sum_{n,m\in[0,N]} (2-\delta_{nm}) \, a_n \cos(n\phi) \, a_m \cos(m\phi),
$$
...which I might then integrate analytically term by term. But this doesn't give me an answer consistent with the numerical approach, so I think I'm making a mistake somewhere.
Thanks.

$$
    \begin{align*}
       I(\phi_1, \phi_2) &= \int_{\phi_1}^{\phi_2} \sum_{n = 0}^N \sum_{m = 0}^N a_n a_m \cos(n\phi)\cos(m\phi)d\phi \\
        &= \sum_{n = 0}^N \sum_{m = 0}^N a_n a_m \int_{\phi_1}^{\phi_2} \cos(n\phi)\cos(m\phi)d\phi
    \end{align*}
$$
If $n \neq m$,
$$
    \int_{\phi_1}^{\phi_2} \cos(n\phi)\cos(m\phi)d\phi = \dfrac{1}{2}\int_{\phi_1}^{\phi_2} [\cos((n + m)\phi) + \cos((n - m)\phi)]d\phi = \dfrac{\sin((n + m)\phi_2) - \sin((n + m)\phi_1)}{2(n + m)} + \dfrac{\sin((n - m)\phi_2) - \sin((n - m)\phi_1)}{2(n - m)}
$$
If $n = m$,
$$
   \int_{\phi_1}^{\phi_2} [\cos(n\phi)]^2 d\phi = \dfrac{1}{2}\int_{\phi_1}^{\phi_2} (1 + \cos(2n\phi))d\phi = \dfrac{\phi_2 - \phi_1}{2} + \dfrac{1}{2}\int_{\phi_1}^{\phi_2} \cos(2n\phi)d\phi = \begin{cases} \dfrac{\phi_2 - \phi_1}{2} + \dfrac{1}{4n}[\sin(2n\phi_2) - \sin(2n\phi_1)], \text{ if } n \neq 0 \\ \phi_2 - \phi_1, \text{ if } n = 0 \end{cases}
$$
Put all of these together to get the final result.

Thank you. I messed up with the leading coefficient somehow; seems obvious in retrospect
